# EC2インスタンス内でcurlはできるのにwgetやpingは通らない。

Tags: python, aws, amazon-ec2

EC2内でcurlはレスポンスが返ってくるのですが、ping, wget, また、pythonのrequests.getなどはレスポンスが返ってこず、そのまま何も出力されません。ctrl+cで止められるのですが、それまではずっと出力されません。アクセスしたurlはwww.google.comです。これはなぜでしょうか?

Comment: EC2そのものよりも、そのEC2が置かれているネットワーク設計に依存するような気がします。しかし、その情報が何もないので何とも言えないです。